# Command to transfer funds Faucet

Tags: wallet, cardano-faucet

I have the `cardano-wallet` and `cardano-node` running on the testnet, but I can't seem to figure out how to transfer `tADA` into a wallet from the `cardano-faucet`

Anybody?

Answer (score 2):

You can visit https://testnets.cardano.org/en/testnets/cardano/tools/faucet/ and enter your wallet address. The faucet gives 1000 tADA per day